# View Profile returns User not found

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile

I have built a Development Environment and imported users to the Profile Store.  When I attempt to access a user's profile, the page returns "Something Went Wrong Here" "user not found".

When I access the Users Profile from Central Administration, it comes up fine. There is nothing in the logs.  Where do I look for clues to the issue ?  (I'm using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise)

Comment: did you check the url in the browser when you get error?

Comment: Yes, I then copied and pasted the proper URL into the browser to access the Users Profile and I get the same error.  This happens for all users that have been imported.

Comment: Also, the user profiles show up in Search Results, but when I click on the link to "View Profile" I get "user not found".  I'm stumped.

Comment: OK, I have some more information.  When I use Enterprise Search to find a user, the View Profile link is "http://mysite.portal.contoso.com/Person.aspx?accountname=CONTOSO%255Caylak"  Which is incorrect.  It shoould be "http://mysite.portal.contoso.com/Person.aspx?accountname=CONTOSO%5Caylak

Comment: Check to see if you have the url encoded for dashes and spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provision a My Site Host along with the User Profile Service. After creating the Web Application create a My Site Host site collection and configure the connection in the User Profile Service Application.

Comment: Been there, done that. Apparently what I found was a bug in the April CU that causes the URL to double up.  If you look closely in my last post, the %255C should be %5C

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug in the April CU.  The June CU Apparently fixes this.